# Splitting array with generic stride?

Tags: arrays, swift, generics

Is this possible to do a generic conversion of floating points and return arbitrary number of arrays?

Perhaps I don't understand how to do arbitrary recursion with arrays?

example
input vector

```
Vector:[CGFloat] = [-0.23,-5.2,0.24,-1.4,4.0,10.2]
```

output vector if stride by 2

```
VectorOut=[[-0.23,0.24,4.0],[-5.2,-1.4,10.2]]
```

output vector if stride by 3

```
VectorOut=[[-0.23,-1.4],[-5.2,4.0],[0.24.10.2]]


func splitArray<T:FloatingPoint>(Vector x:[T], byStride N: Int)->([T],[T],...[byStride])
{
  guard (x.count % byStride == 0) else {"BOMB \(#file) \(#line) \(#function)"
  return [NaN]
}       

var index:[Int] = [Int](repeating: 0.0, count: byStride)
var bigVector:[[T]] = [T](repeating: 0.0, count: byStride)

for idx in index {

 for elem in stride(from:idx, to: x.count - 1 - idx, by:byStride){
 bigVector[idx]=x[idx]
  }
 }
return bigVector


}
```

Comment: Show sample input and desired output, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot return a variable-sized tuple. What you can do is to
return a nested array.

Example (hoping that I interpreted the problem correctly):

```
func splitArray<T>(vector x:[T], byStride N: Int) -> [[T]] {
    precondition(x.count % N == 0, "stride must evenly divide the array count")
    return (0..<N).map { stride(from: $0, to: x.count, by: N).map { x[$0] } }
}

let a = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]

print(splitArray(vector: a, byStride: 2))
// [[1.0, 3.0, 5.0], [2.0, 4.0, 6.0]]

print(splitArray(vector: a, byStride: 3))
// [[1.0, 4.0], [2.0, 5.0], [3.0, 6.0]]
```

---

*Explanation:* `(0..<N).map { ... }` creates an array of size `N`.
For each value `$0`,

```
stride(from: $0, to: x.count, by: N).map { x[$0] }
```

creates the "stride" of `x` starting at index `$0` with increment `N`:

```
[ x[$0], x[$0+N], x[$0+2*N], ..., x[x.count-N+$0] ]
```

Comment: Thanks!  yes that is what I was trying to do, dynamically assign the output based on the stride thinking that recursion might be the way to go.   With this type of generic, it will handle anything comparable?

Comment: @GAlexander: The function does not put a restriction on `T`, it will work with *any* array.